# Подгрузка изображений через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Нужно по клику выгружать изображения по ajax с сервера.
Но возвращается пустой массив, хотя количество элементов массива соответствует количеству файлов.
**routes/web.php**

```
    //Route::get('/cars/images', 'CarController@carImages')->name('cars.images');
    Route::post('/cars/images', 'CarController@carImages')->name('cars.images');
```

**controller**

```
    public function carImages(Request $request){
        $images = collect(File::allFiles(public_path('/images/catalog')) );
//        $images = File::allFiles(public_path('/images/catalog'));
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'images' => $images,
        ]);
//        return response([
//            'status' => 'ok',
//            'images' => $images,
//        ]);
    }
```

**view**

```
<button class="js-image-load" data-url="{{ route('cars.images') }}">click</button>
```

**js**

```
    var page = 1;
    $('.js-image-load').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var data = {
            page: page,
        };
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            // dataType: 'html',
            // async: false,
            // crossDomain: 'true',
            // processData: false,
            // contentType: false,
            // dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            },
        });
    });
```

в результате возвращаются такие данные:

```
images: Array(7)
0:
__proto__: Object
1: {}
2: {}
3: {}
4: {}
5: {}
6: {}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
status: "ok"
```

Подскажите, как подгружать изображения с сервера по ajax?

```
    public function carImages(Request $request){
        $cars = Car::get();
        $images = collect(File::allFiles(public_path('/images/catalog')) );
//        $images = File::allFiles(public_path('/images/catalog'));
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'images' => $images,
            'cars' => $cars
        ]);
//        return response([
//            'status' => 'ok',
//            'images' => $images,
//        ]);
    }
```

в данном случае в элементе `cars` содержатся корректные данные из базы из таблицы `cars`,
а изображения почему-то не приходят

Comment: А зачем возвращать файлы если можно возвращать пути к файлам и через цикл проставлять их в img?

Comment: @InDevX, а как из коллекции `$images` возвратить пути подскажете?

Comment: А зачем вам коллекция? Просто из базы извлекайте где они хранятся

Comment: @InDevX, некоторые изображения не хранятся в базе из папки `images`, поэтому нужно извлекать с помощью `File`

Comment: Можно как-то так `collect(File::allFiles(public_path('/images/catalog'))->map(function($file) { return Storage::url($file); })` или без коллекции просто возвращать `File::allFiles(public_path('/images/catalog')` и где выводится через `asset()` подставлять файл

Comment: @InDevX, подскажите ещё, почему не работает метод `get` в вышеприведённом маршруте? т.е. если поменять из `post` на `get` и в js `method: 'post'` то вообще ничего не будет возвращать по клику

Comment: Возможно надо csrf токен добавлять заголовки запроса. Там ошибка должна выводится если что-то не корректно

Comment: нет, это не из-за csrf токен, post-запрос ведь работает. csrf токен добавляется

Comment: `Route::get('/cars/images/{page}', 'CarController@carImages')->name('cars.images');`

Comment: `<button class="js-image-load" data-url="{{ route('cars.images',1) }}">click</button>`. в js `method: 'get'`

Comment: заработало так, но пришлось добавить параметр в маршрут `{page}`, почему так происходит объясните пожалуйста?

Comment: csrf токен добавляется в $.ajaxSetup

Comment: Да, в ajaxSetup. GET не работал потому что параметры через ссылку передавать надо, всё верно, но непонятно почему ошибки не было, в таких случаях exception должен вылетать. Ну и тут не особо принципиально get или post использовать.. По сути, абсолютно все запросы можно посредством post делать